# ¿Como desplazar el contenido del body con el menu lateral y hacerlo dinámico para pantalla pequeñas?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap, responsive

¿ Que debo hacer para que el contenido del body sea dinámico al ocultar y mostrar el Menú Lateral ?
Estoy tratando de crear un proyecto con PHP de administración de productos.

He creado un Menú Lateral, para lo que utilice una plantilla.
El Menú Lateral también tiene una barra de navegación que contiene el botón que utilizamos para ocultar y mostrar el Menú Lateral

[image: Menu Lateral]

Las paginas o vistas nuevas, se añaden por medio de `php`, y Quiero que el contenido de las páginas que añado nuevas, ocupe toda la pantalla, con un `margin-left: 40px` a la izquierda y se desplace dinámicamente cuando mostramos el Menú Lateral
Cuando añado una nueva pagina, se presentan dos problemas:

- El contenido de la nueva pagina se sobrepone sobre la barra de navegación y se oculta debajo de la Barra Lateral.

[image: el contenido de body sobrepone al NavBar]

Esto de primeras lo he corregido añadiendo `margin-top` y `margin-left`

```
.bodis {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 330px!important;
}
```

Pero esto no es muy dinámico, ya que cuando oculto la Barra Lateral, el contenido de las paginas queda en el centro de la pagina y cuando se reduce el tamaño de la pantalla, el contenido incluso desaparece.

[image: contenido en pantallas pequeñas]

***Otra captura de pantalla***

[image: espacio muy grande]

La plantilla utiliza varios framework para css y javascript que muestro a continuación. He leído documentación de alguno de ellos, como Bootstrap, pero no me quedo claro cual seria la mejor forma de hacer el contenido dinámico para cada una de las pantallas que añada al proyecto

1. Bootstrap V4.3

   Bootstrap Material Design V4.0

   Font Awesome V5.9.0

   Sweet Alerts V8.13.0 CSS file

   jQuery Custom Content Scroller V3.1.5
2. ------ javascript ----

   jQuery V3.4.1

   popper

   Bootstrap V4.3

¿ Como puedo hacer el contenido dinámico y efectivo en dispositivos móviles ?

¿ Como puedo hacer que el contenido de la pagina ocupe casi todo la pantalla y se desplace al mostrar el Menu Lateral ?

¿ Puedo utilizar alguno de los framework que utiliza la plantilla ?

He creado [un repositorio en GitHub](https://github.com/miguelAppStudio/Inventario-Php-MySQL) con el proyecto donde el menu lateral es el archivo /inc/menu.php, y las vistas que se van añadiendo al proyecto estan en la carpeta "vistas" en este caso es /vistas/home.php

Las vistas que se van añadiendo mediante el archivo index.php( es el comienzo de todo)
En mi proyecto los iconos les tengo en local y no se como añadirlo mediante enlace cnd, Me falta añadir el boton en la demo que se nuestra abajo no se ve el botón para mostrar el Menu Lateral, pero pasando el raton encima de la apalabra HOME, si que actua.

Muestro el código de la barra del Menú Lateral y el de Una de las vista, en este caso el Home y tra
VISTA DE HOME:

```
<div class="bodis">
  <div class="full-box page-header">
    <h1 class="title">Home</h1>
    <h2>BIENVENIDO ESTO ES EL HOME</h2>
  </div>

</div>
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

        /*  Show/Hidden Submenus */
        $('.nav-btn-submenu').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var SubMenu=$(this).next('ul');
            var iconBtn=$(this).children('.fa-chevron-down');
            if(SubMenu.hasClass('show-nav-lateral-submenu')){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                iconBtn.removeClass('fa-rotate-180');
                SubMenu.removeClass('show-nav-lateral-submenu');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('active');
                iconBtn.addClass('fa-rotate-180');
                SubMenu.addClass('show-nav-lateral-submenu');
            }
        });

        /*  Show/Hidden Nav Lateral */
        $('.show-nav-lateral').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var NavLateral=$('.nav-lateral');
            var PageConten=$('.page-content');
            if(NavLateral.hasClass('active')){
                NavLateral.removeClass('active');
                PageConten.removeClass('active');
            }else{
                NavLateral.addClass('active');
                PageConten.addClass('active');
            }
        });

        /*  Exit system buttom */
     $('.btn-exit-system').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            Swal.fire({
                title: '¿Estás seguro de cerrar la sesión?',
                text: "Está a punto de cerrar la sesión y salir del sistema",
                type: 'question',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: 'Si, Salir',
                cancelButtonText: 'No, cancelar'
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.value) {
                    window.location="index.php?vista=login";
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```css
@font-face {
        font-family: 'roboto_medium_regular';
        src: url('../webfonts/roboto-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('../webfonts/roboto-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'roboto_condensed_light';
        src: url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'roboto_condensed_regular';
        src: url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('../webfonts/robotocondensed-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }

    :root{
        --color-one: #F5F5F5;
        --color-two: #24292E;
        --color-three: #EC5252;
        /*--color-three: #0366D6;*/

        --form-color: #14111A;

        --accent-color: #253556;
        /*--accent-color: #455A64;*/
        --border-color: #D8D8D8;
    }

   /* .bodis {
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: 330px!important;
    }
*/

    body,html{
        font-family: 'roboto_condensed_light';
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: var(--color-one);
        color: #333;
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .full-box{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .form-neon{
        border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
        background-color: #FFF;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    /*----------  Page headers styles  ----------*/
    .page-header{
        padding: 30px 20px 60px 20px;
    }
    .page-header > :nth-child(1){
        padding-bottom: 7px;
    }
    .page-header > :nth-child(2){
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    /*----------  Page nav tabs  ----------*/
    .page-nav-tabs{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .page-nav-tabs li,
    .page-nav-tabs li a{
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }
    .page-nav-tabs li{
        margin: 5px 20px;
    }
    .page-nav-tabs li a{
        color: var(--accent-color);
        font-size: 17px;
        min-width: 200px;
        width: auto;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        user-select: none;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    }
    .page-nav-tabs li a.active{
        color: var(--color-three);
        cursor: none;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .page-nav-tabs li a:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
    }

    /*----------  Edit bootstrap styles  ----------*/
    .form-control[readonly]{
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    .form-control:focus,
    .form-control:active{
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .form-control-file:active,
    .form-control-file:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
    .table .btn{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .table thead th{
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .table tbody tr{
        color: #333;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .table-dark,
    .table{
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    .table-dark{
        border: 1px solid var(--accent-color);
    }
    .table-dark thead tr{
        background-color: var(--accent-color);
    }
    .table-dark td,
    .table-dark thead th,
    .table-dark th{
        border: none;
    }
    .table-dark tr:hover{
        color: var(--color-three);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, rgba(124, 100, 112, .2) 85%, transparent);
    }
    .page-link{
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .page-link:hover{
        background-color: var(--color-three);
        color: #FFF;
    }
    table form{
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    /*----------  Text Styles  ----------*/
    .roboto-medium{
        font-family: 'roboto_medium_regular';
    }
    .roboto-condensed-light{
        font-family: 'roboto_condensed_light';
    }
    .roboto-condensed-regular{
        font-family: 'roboto_condensed_regular';
    }

    /*----------  login Styles  ----------*/
    .login-container{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: #0575E6;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #021B79, #0575E6);
        background: linear-gradient(to right, #021B79, #0575E6);

    }
    .login-content{
        width: 95%;
        max-width: 320px;
        height: auto;
        border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 15px;
        color: var(--accent-color);
    }
    .btn-login{
        width: 90%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: var(--accent-color);
        border: 1px solid var(--accent-color);
        transition: all .2s ease-out;
    }
    .btn-login:hover{
        background-color: var(--color-three);
        border: 1px solid var(--color-three);
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .btn-login:active,
    .btn-login:focus{
        outline: none;
    }

    /*----------  Page layout Styles  ----------*/
    .main-container{
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .page-content,
    .nav-lateral{
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .page-content{
        position: fixed;
        padding-left: 300px;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    /*  Nav Lateral */
    .nav-lateral{
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        background-image: url('../assets/img/nav-font.jpg');
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .nav-lateral-bg{ display: none; }
    .nav-lateral-content{
        max-width: 300px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(36, 41, 46, .8);
    }
    .nav-lateral-bar{
        height: 3px;
        background-color: var(--color-three);
    }
    .nav-lateral-avatar{
        padding: 40px 0;
    }
    .nav-lateral-avatar i{
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-lateral-avatar img{
        width: 50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
        border: 4px solid #FFF;
        border-radius: 100%;
    }
    .nav-lateral-avatar figcaption{
        margin-top: 20px;
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .nav-lateral-menu{
        height: auto;
    }
    .nav-lateral-menu ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .nav-lateral-menu ul li{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .nav-lateral-menu ul li a{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 45px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 17px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-left: 20px;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .nav-lateral-menu ul li a.active{
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: var(--color-three);
    }
    .nav-lateral-menu ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 50%, transparent);
    }
    .nav-lateral-menu ul li ul{
        display: none;
        border: 1px solid var(--color-three);
        background: rgba(20, 30, 48, .5);
    }
    .nav-lateral-menu ul li ul a{
        padding-left: 45px;
    }
    .show-nav-lateral-submenu{
        display: block !important;
    }
    .nav-lateral-menu .fa-chevron-down,
    .nav-lateral-menu .fa-chevron-up{
        float: right;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 45px;
        margin-right: 7px;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    /*  Page content */
    .navbar-info{
        height: 50px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color);
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .navbar-info a{
        color: var(--accent-color);
        height: 50px;
        min-width: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
        transition: all .2s ease-out;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .navbar-info a:hover{
        color: var(--color-three);
        background-image: radial-gradient(circle,rgba(250, 30, 78, .1), transparent 80%);
    }
    .navbar-info a:active,
    .navbar-info a:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
    /*----------  Breakpoints  ----------*/
    @media (max-width: 767px){
        .nav-lateral{
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: none;
            background-image: none;
        }
        .nav-lateral.active{
            display: block;
            z-index: 9999;
        }
        .nav-lateral-bg{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, .4);
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .nav-lateral-content{
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 3;
            transform: translateX(-400px);
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
            background-color: var(--color-two);
        }
        .nav-lateral.active .nav-lateral-content{
            transform: translateX(0);
        }
        .nav-lateral-avatar i{
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            line-height: 50px;
            color: #FFF;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 25px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;
            right: 0;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            transition: all .2s ease-out;
        }
        .nav-lateral-avatar i:hover{
            color: var(--color-three);
        }
        .page-content{
            padding-left: 0;
        }
    }


    /*  Bootstrap breakpoints */
    @media (min-width: 576px){

    }

    @media (min-width: 768px){
        .nav-lateral.active{
            transform: translateX(-400px);
        }
        .page-content.active{
            padding-left: 0;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px){

    }

    @media (min-width: 1200px){

    }
```

```html
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/latest/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/4.0.0/bootstrap-material-design.iife.min.js">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Main container -->
        <main class="full-box main-container">
          <!-- Nav lateral -->
          <section class="full-box nav-lateral">
            <div class="full-box nav-lateral-bg show-nav-lateral"></div>
            <div class="full-box nav-lateral-content">
              <figure class="full-box nav-lateral-avatar">
                <i class="far fa-times-circle show-nav-lateral"></i>
                <img src="./assets/avatar/Avatar.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Avatar">
                <figcaption class="roboto-medium text-center">
                Leading Company <br><small class="roboto-condensed-light">Panel Administración</small>
                </figcaption>
              </figure>
              <div class="full-box nav-lateral-bar"></div>
              <nav class="full-box nav-lateral-menu">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="home.html"><i class="fab fa-dashcube fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Dashboard</a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu"><i class="fas fa-users fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Clientes <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="client-new.html"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Agregar Cliente</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="client-list.html"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Lista de clientes</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="client-search.html"><i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Buscar cliente</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu"><i class="fas fa-pallet fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Items <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="item-new.html"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Agregar item</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="item-list.html"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Lista de items</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="item-search.html"><i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Buscar item</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Préstamos <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="reservation-new.html"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Nuevo préstamo</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="reservation-list.html"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Lista de
                          préstamos</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="reservation-search.html"><i class="fas fa-search-dollar fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Buscar
                          préstamos</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="reservation-pending.html"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Préstamos
                          pendientes</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu"><i class="fas  fa-user-secret fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Usuarios <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="user-new.html"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Nuevo usuario</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="user-list.html"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Lista de usuarios</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="user-search.html"><i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Buscar usuario</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                    <a href="company.html"><i class="fas fa-store-alt fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Empresa</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </section>

          <!-- Page content -->
          <section class=" full-box page-content">
            <nav class="fexid-top full-box navbar-info">
              <a href="#" class="float-left show-nav-lateral">
                <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="btn-exit-system">
                <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>
              </a>
            </nav>


          </section>
        </main>
        <div class="bodis">
      <div class="full-box page-header">
        <h1 class="title">Home</h1>
        <h2>BIENVENIDO ESTO ES EL HOME</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú tienes implementado un sistema para el menú abra y cierre. Este sistema ocupa una clase `page-content` para el contenido. Entonces solo es necesario ocupar esta clase y lo tienes

Tu main queda:

```
<div class="bodis page-content">
    <div class="full-box page-header">
        <h1 class="title">Home</h1>
        <h2>
            Bienvenido al panel de Administradción <?php echo $_SESSION['nombre']." ".$_SESSION['apellido']; ?>!
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Solo agregamos `page-content` al lado de `bodi`

---

Luego debemos arreglar el css de la clase bodi

```
.bodis {
    margin-top: 80px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

---

Capturas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Pequeñas otras mejoras, que vi al pasar (estas no están relacionadas con el problema de la pregunta):

Para que la barra del menú no ocupe todo el width en movil:

Cambiar el width a 300px (línea 598 de stylos.css)

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.nav-lateral-bg {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(3, 3, 3, .4);
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Quitar la clase fullbox en varias partes da un padding-top raro. Sobre todo en menu.php

```
<main class="full-box main-container">
  <!-- Nav lateral -->
  <section class="full-box nav-lateral">
```

---

UPDATE:

Tu css debe quedar así:

Creamos una clase content para colocar el contenido

```
.bodis {
    margin-top: 80px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width:100%;
}
.bodis .content {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Y Todas las vistas que tengas tienes que tener el siguiente esquema:

```
<div class="bodis page-content">
   <div class="content">
     <h1 class="title ">Título</h1>
     <h2 class="subtitle">Subtitulo</h2>
     
     <!-- EL RESTO DEL CONTENIDO --!>
     <!-- NO colocar  class="container pb-6 pt-6" --!>
   </div>
</div>
```

Ejemplo con vista user_new.php

```
<div class="bodis page-content">
    <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title ">Usuarios</h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle">Nuevo usuario</h2>

        <form action="./php/usuario_guardar.php" method="POST" class="FormularioAjax" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column">

<!-- Etc --!>
```

Comment: Realmente es increíble, has revisado el proyecto afondo. Esta bien solo que en el resto de pantallas no funciona. Por ejemplo en user_new.php, el contenido lo oculta el Sidebar y no se desplaza a la derecha, te muestro [algunas capturas de pantalla.](https://ibb.co/khhyF81)  El resto de pantallas que añado al proyecto, llevaran el css con Bulma, es el mismo del tutorial y no quiero improvisar mas asta que aprenda. Otras pantallas, [queda padding en la parte derecha:](https://ibb.co/k0Sj0dT) cuando [oculto el Sidebar](https://ibb.co/dcDkZKb) He tratado de corregir esto pero no encuentro forma

Comment: En home todo funciona, solo lleva ese css, pero el resto de pantallas @Yussef, no se como solucionarlo. Tiene por defecto de Bulma, y he probado cual estilos modificar, pero no encuentro la forma. Todas tienen un `div con `container is-fluid mb-6` para el titulo y luego estan envueltas en `container pb-6 pt-6`. ¿ Tiene esto algo que ver?. Disculpa la demora en responder, primero queria tratar de corregir estos problemas, pero no logro solucionarlo. Otra cosa,¿ quieres que elimine `full-box`de todos los sitios ? al añadir `page-content`al resto de pantallas, no funciona los botones de la NavBar

Comment: @unity-student Ese container está de sobra por eso hay que sacarlo, yo te di la solución para que pudieras implementarla en todas las otras vistas. Lo que pasa mi estimado, es que tienes div y clases por todos lados, no respetaste el formato de las librerías que ocupas, que no es tan malo si se sabe hacer. Actualicé mi respuesta (con un Update abajo) para darte una idea de cómo debes ir configurando tus otras vistas.

Comment: Gracias, hare pruebas pero con tu actualización lo tengo un poco más claro. Aunque debo estudiar mucho, mucho aún. Debo añadir algunas vistas más y esto me ayudara. Como dices, tengo un poco de revuelo de css. Sigo un curso en linea y la interfaz de usuario del curso no me gusta, entonces,  mi problema es que quiero hacerla de otro modo, cojo ejemplos que encuentro en internet para una cosa y luego cuando creo otro apartado, añado ejemplos que encuentro con otro framework. Esto añadido a mi escasa experiencia, se embarulla todo. Espero esto me sirva para organizar mejor los proyectos

Comment: @unity-student Ahh estas recién aprendiendo, es lo normal tener un revoltijo en los css al principio, lo que te puedo recomendar es que aprender a usar el modo desarrollo de los navegadores (tecla F12) y aprender CSS antes que aprender librerías, estas últimas pasan de moda pero el conocimiento base (CSS) sirve para todo. Mucha Suerte en tu proyecto!!

Comment: Gracias, seguire tus ideas. Muchas gracias por tu poyo, es posible que me encuentres por aquí más veces ):):

Comment: Disculpa @Yussef, hasta ahora cuando reducía el tamaño de la pantalla, el Sidebar se volvia transparente en pantalla reducida. Esto ya no ocurre, no que que e cambiado que se rompió, ¿Puedes ayudarme con esto o hago otra pregunta ? Unicamente lo comento aqui porque vi que tienes controlado el proyecto. Y por supuesto, esto no quiere decir que vuelva hacerte más preguntas respecto a esto. Es una cosa puntual no se si es bueno que te pregunte o que haga una nueva pregunta. Con lo que sea, estare igual agradecido

Comment: He agregado `opacity: .5` a la case `.nav-lateral.active`, no se si esta es la forma mas indicada

Comment: @unity-student si opacity es para eso. La otra forma de hacerlo es colocar el background-color: rbga(233,45,12, 0.5). Donde el último número indica la transparencia (de 0 a 1, donde 0.5 es el 50%) y los primero 3 valores son el color el RBG (de 0 a 255), también funciona con el formato habitual (#faebd780) agregando otro par de números al final

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer fácilmente utilizando Javascript con dos funciones y un botón.
Primero te enseñaré una pequeña demo y luego esa tecnología aplicada a tu prototipo.

**DEMO**

```js
//JavaScript
// Esta función pone el width a 250px, entonces el contenido del sidebar se puede ver
// El botón Panel inicializa esta función
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
}
// Esta función pone el width a 0px, entonces el contenido del sidebar ya no se puede ver
// El botón con una cruz inicializa esta función 
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
}
```

```css
/*Esto es un poco de CSS para darle estilo  */

body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!--HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<!--Esto es el sidebar, en un prinicipio estará oculto  -->
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <!--Cuando el botón con la cruz sea activado, entonces se activará la función JavaScript closeNav, que cierra el sidebar  -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
<!--Declaramos un botón con onclick, cuando este botón sea accionado entonces la función en JavaScript openNav se activará-->
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>  
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapse_sidebar.asp" >#Referencia</a>
</div>


   
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora con tus códigos implementamos la misma solución.

**Implementación de la DEMO con tu código**

```js
// JavaScript

function openNav() {
   
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
  document.getElementById("boton").style.color = "white";
 
}

function closeNav() {
  
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
  document.getElementById("boton").style.color = "black";
  
}
```

```css
/* CSS */
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
   background-color: rgba(245, 245, 220,0.4);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  border-color: white;
  background-color: white;
 
  padding: 10px 28px;
  font-size: 17px;
 
}

.openbtn:hover {
   
   color: white;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}

.navbar-info{
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.navbar-info a{
    color: var(--accent-color);
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    user-select: none;
}
.navbar-info a:hover{
    color: var(--color-three);
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle,rgba(250, 30, 78, .1), transparent 80%);
}
.navbar-info a:active,
.navbar-info a:focus{
    outline: none;
}

.page-content,
.nav-lateral{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.page-content{
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 300px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
/*  Nav Lateral */
.nav-lateral{
    width: 300px;
    
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    background-image: url(https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1353553203/photo/forest-wooden-table-background-summer-sunny-meadow-with-green-grass-forest-trees-background.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=-jvR1WDwcloLXRgRTGeyG3frvrhPIbegdemeL6vY2Pk=);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.nav-lateral-bg{ display: none; }
.nav-lateral-content{
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(36, 41, 46, .8);
}
.nav-lateral-bar{
    height: 3px;
    background-color: var(--color-three);
}
.nav-lateral-avatar{
    padding: 40px 0;
}
.nav-lateral-avatar i{
    display: none;
}
.nav-lateral-avatar img{
    width: 40%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.nav-lateral-avatar figcaption{
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.nav-lateral-menu{
    height: auto;
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 17px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li a.active{
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: var(--color-three);
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, rgba(255, 255, 255, .1) 50%, transparent);
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li ul{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-three);
    background: rgba(20, 30, 48, .5);
}
.nav-lateral-menu ul li ul a{
    padding-left: 45px;
}
.show-nav-lateral-submenu{
    display: block !important;
}
.nav-lateral-menu .fa-chevron-down,
.nav-lateral-menu .fa-chevron-up{
    float: right;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  
  <section class="full-box nav-lateral">
    <div class="full-box nav-lateral-bg show-nav-lateral"></div>
    <div class="full-box nav-lateral-content">
      <figure class="full-box nav-lateral-avatar">
        <i class="far fa-times-circle show-nav-lateral"></i>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRw7nCP6btxb_wUbB2bqwtG3XT3vSC3PcIWyw&usqp=CAU" class="img-fluid" alt="Avatar">
        <figcaption style="margin-left:12%; !important" class="roboto-medium text-center">
        Leading Company <br><small class="roboto-condensed-light">Panel Administración</small>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class="full-box nav-lateral-bar"></div>
      <nav class="full-box nav-lateral-menu">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="home.html"><i class="fab fa-dashcube fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Dashboard</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu"><i class="fas fa-users fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Clientes <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="client-new.html"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Agregar Cliente</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="client-list.html"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Lista de clientes</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="client-search.html"><i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Buscar cliente</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu"><i class="fas fa-pallet fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Items <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="item-new.html"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Agregar item</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="item-list.html"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Lista de items</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="item-search.html"><i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Buscar item</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu"><i class="fas fa-file-invoice-dollar fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Préstamos <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="reservation-new.html"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Nuevo préstamo</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="reservation-list.html"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Lista de
                  préstamos</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="reservation-search.html"><i class="fas fa-search-dollar fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Buscar
                  préstamos</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="reservation-pending.html"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Préstamos
                  pendientes</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-btn-submenu"><i class="fas  fa-user-secret fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Usuarios <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="user-new.html"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Nuevo usuario</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="user-list.html"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Lista de usuarios</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="user-search.html"><i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Buscar usuario</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="company.html"><i class="fas fa-store-alt fa-fw"></i> &nbsp; Empresa</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Page content -->
  <section class=" full-box page-content">
    <nav class="fexid-top full-box navbar-info">
      <a href="#" class="float-left show-nav-lateral">
        <i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn-exit-system">
        <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>
      </a>
    </nav>


  </section>
  
  
  
</div>

<div id="main">
  <a  class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()"><p id="boton"> Panel ☰</p></a>  
  <h2>BIENVENIDO ESTO ES EL HOME</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Notas:**

**-** Este prototipo es responsive en el `width`, pero no en el `height`, intenta con medias reduciendo los espacios y la letra que te quepa todos los apartados del sidebar.

**-** Para esconder el botón Panel hago algo rápido, pongo el texto en blanco cuando el sidebar está activado. Existen otras metodologías más atractivas para hacer la misma función, investiga.

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: Pero mi código ya tiene el botón para ocultar y mostrar el Sidebar. Quizá no se ve en la ejecución por que no pude añadir todo el tengo librerías en archivo, no de forma CND . Tratare de editarlo para que se muestre. Bueno, en las capturas de pantalla si puede verse el botón. Te recuerdo, que lo que se muestra en el body, es un archivo diferente al sidebar, muestro el código : VISTA DE HOME, apenas 6 lineas. Todas las pantallas que tenga la app deberán llevar el mismo css para ser responsive. Entonces, yo necesito css, ¿ Cual es el que debo utilizar de tu DEMO ?

Comment: Mi botón es el que esta en la sección `<!-- Page content -->`. Quiza pueda utilizar tu función para añadirlo a este

Comment: He tratado añadir tus demos a mi proyecto pero no funciona. Tambien he tratado de añadir más detalles de mi código pero no me es posible, asi que estoy creando u n repositorio para que pueda ayudarme un amigo y aprovecho para que se pueda ver en esta pregunta.